# Condition for divergent series

Tags: divergent-series

When studying the material of convergent series, I came up with a question.

Is $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \ne 0$ a sufficient and necessary condition for the series $∑a_n$ to be divergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n$ does not go to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, then the sum will not converge.

However, even if it goes to $0$, the sum could still diverge, say $a_n=\cfrac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient, but not necessary, as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ but this gives the well-known harmonic series $$\sum\frac{1}{n}.$$We can check this diverges, for example, by the integral test.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient, but not necessary.  For example, the harmonic series
$$\sum \frac{1}{n}$$
diverges, even though
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

not necessary since $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, it is sufficient though as if $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ converges, then $a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ converges to $0$ (here $S_n$ is the partial sum $a_1+\cdots +a_n$).